# getElementsByFieldName ? Get all elements of a radioenum that have a certain field name

Tags: javascript

I have a radioenum html that looks like

```
<div class="col-xs-12" type="radioenum" field="arr_c">
// elements
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the elements it contains, but not sure how to proceed

There's no function called getElementsByFieldName that can be called and class name is not unique so I can't use getElementsByClassName

Comment: You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) if you want to grab the first element on the page that matches the selector or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you want to grab all of them.

(NB: `enum` is a reserved word so you can't call your variable names that I just found out)

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radioenum"');
radios.forEach(radio => console.log(radio.textContent));
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12" type="radioenum" field="arr_c">
  Test 1
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" type="not-radioenum" field="arr_c">
  Test 2
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" type="radioenum" field="arr_c">
  Test 3
</div>
```

Edit

One thing I've just noticed is that both `type` and `field` are invalid attributes. You can use `type` on a number of elements [but `div` is not one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). So, first you should switch those attributes to `data-` attributes. You can pick up the data-attribute in the same way and then, in the loop, you can destructure the field attribute out from the current element and check its value.

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="radioenum"]');

radios.forEach(radio => {
  const { dataset: { field } } = radio;
  if (field === 'arr_c') {
    console.log('Found arr_c');
  } else {
    console.log(radio.textContent)
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12" data-type="radioenum" data-field="arr_a">
  Test 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" data-type="not-radioenum" data-field="arr_b">
  Test 2
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" data-type="radioenum" data-field="arr_c">
  Test 3
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, do you know how i could identify the specific radioenum that has field="arr_c" when inside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelector()` instead and you can select the element by its attributes.  It will return the first matching `Element`, just like `getElementById()`.

Example:

```
document.querySelector("[type=radioenum]");
```

If you need to capture multiple inputs, you can also use `querySelectorAll()`, but it will return a `NodeList`, instead of an `Element`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=radioenum]");
```